# Implementation Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking for resources on Microsoft Sync Framework. Although MSDN and Google Search gave me the brief overview,but I want simple example of demos,implementations of the Sync framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

[Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0 October 2010 CTP Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg299051%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Contains documentation, tutorials and samples.

EDIT:

---

Perhaps also some [introduction videos to the Microsoft sync framework.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/cc667386)

Comment: thanks Alex, it is helpful but I am looking for some simple tutorials/ resources on Microsoft Sync Framework. MSDN provides a solution which is little bit complex. Here I am expecting some more explained and simple resources on it.

Comment: No worries @shivank I've added a link to some intro videos as well, perhaps they'll be helpful.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith can we use sync framework for 2 sql express dbs, any update for .net 4.5?

Comment: Hi @Dragon I'm afraid I've not looked at the sync framework for a very long time, to be honest I forgot was it was I had to look at my own link! There's a few people's names on here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/ perhaps you'd like to reach out to them.

Answer (score 0):

you havent mentioned what you want to sync: files? databases? feeds?
if you install Sync Framework itself, the documentation comes with tutorials/walkthroughs especially on database synchronization.

for database sync, you can take a look at:

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: what about two sql express databasurces

Comment: Sql Express uses the same SqlSyncProvider, so should work