# resource/tutorials to implement a microsoft sync framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking for the resource/tutorials to implement a microsoft sync framework. I want to create a application to achieve Bidirectional synchronization. I have already gone through MSDN. As I am new to this, I want simple tutorials and implementation guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out this screencast?

http://www.bestechvideos.com/2008/05/29/mix08-using-the-microsoft-sync-framework-and-feedsync

Comment: it is helpful however I am looking for microsoft sync framework for synchronization of databases.

Answer (score 2):

seems to be a duplicate post of this same question: [Implementation Microsoft Sync Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491132/implementation-microsoft-sync-framework)

anyway, if you install Sync Framework itself, the documentation comes with tutorials/walkthroughs especially on database synchronization.

for database sync, you can take a look at:

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)