# Using Microsoft Sync Framework for Multiple Offline (LAN-Connected) Local Databases?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, microsoft-sync-framework, localdb, data-synchronization

I have several computers which, in their production environment, will only be connected to each other via LAN. There will be no Internet connection. Each computer is going to start off with an identical copy of an application with a local database. As the application is used on each computer, I would like to use Microsoft Sync Framework to periodically sync the changes between local databases over the LAN. I do not plan to use any of these computers as a centralized server. Note that I'm using SQL Express 2012 LocalDB and not SQL Server Compact Edition due to a need for stored procedures in my application.

I'm posing a two-part question:

1) Is it possible to accomplish what I want with Microsoft Sync Framework?

2) If so, could someone please help me begin by providing some manner of reference material or advice on the topic to point me in the right direction?

Please Note: I'm aware that two other questions have been asked about getting started with Microsoft Sync Framework before: [resource/tutorials to implement a microsoft sync framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491380/resource-tutorials-to-implement-a-microsoft-sync-framework/6494286#6494286) and [Implementation Microsoft Sync Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491132/implementation-microsoft-sync-framework). I have gone through the answers on both of these, and not found any actionable information which I feel pertains to my situation.

Comment: If everybody starts with the same.my question is dos everybody edit different things or is het posible differt users edit the same?

Comment: They're all making changes to the same data. This is a check-in application of sorts, so once one person has been checked in through one computer, I don't want them to be able to go through again. If the data is synced often enough, I think this can easily be caught. The one computer just needs to tell all the others that "person x" has now checked in and have them update their local databases accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to use 1 database.but I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be possible. Sync Fx can work in peer-to-peer fashion.

the out-of-the-box SqlSyncProvider should work with SQLServer, SQLExpress, LocalDB and Azure SQL.

have a look at this [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll give it a try as soon as I can and accept your answer if it helps me out.